# How to get total number of aggregation buckets in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I use Elasticsearch terms aggregation to see how many documents have a certain value in their "foo" field like this:

```
{
    ...
    "aggregations": {
        "metastore": { 
            "terms": { 
                "field": "foo",
                "size": 50 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I get the response:

```
 "aggregations": {
      "foo": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1538352000000,
                    "doc_count": 935
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1541030400000,
                    "doc_count": 15839
                },
                ...
                /* 48 more values */
             ]
      }
 }
```

But I'm limiting the number of different values to 50. If there are more different values in this field they won't be returned in the response, and that's fine, because I don't need to all of them, but I would like to know how many of them there are. So, how could I get the total number of different values? It would be fantastic if the answer provided a full example query, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably add a [cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) which will give you unique number of terms for the field. This will be equal to the number of buckets for the terms aggregation.

```
{
    ...
    "aggregations": {
        "metastore": { 
            "terms": { 
                "field": "foo",
                "size": 50 
            }
        },
        "uniquefoo": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "foo"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: Please keep in mind that cardinality aggregation might in some cases return approx count. To know more on it read [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_counts_are_approximate).

Answer (score 1):

The [`cardinality` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) is there to help. Just note, however, that the number that is returned is an [approximation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_counts_are_approximate) and might not reflect the exact number of buckets you'd get if you were to request them all. However, the accuracy is pretty good on low cardinality fields.

```
{
    ...
    "aggregations": {
        "unique_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "foo"
          }
        },
        "metastore": { 
            "terms": { 
                "field": "foo",
                "size": 50 
            }
        }
    }
}
```